# Bluemix push error

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, push

i'm getting an error when I try to push to BlueMix from local.

```
> node lib/install.js

> optipng-bin@3.1.4 postinstall /tmp/app/node_modules/img-loader/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin
✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

> pngquant-bin@3.1.1 postinstall /tmp/app/node_modules/img-loader/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully

> gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall /tmp/app/node_modules/img-loader/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

✔ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully
/tmp/buildpacks/cbed2b9b0603a1febfaafeebb556dd0b/lib/dependencies.sh: line 1:   163 Killed                  npm install --unsafe-perm --userconfig $build_dir/.npmrc 2>&1
-----> Build failed
Failed to compile droplet

Check our support community to get help on common issues:
http://ibm.biz/bluemixcommunitysupport
If you need additional help and your subscription includes support, submit a ticket so we can help:
http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport

Exit status 223
Staging failed: Exited with status 223 (out of memory)
Destroying container
Successfully destroyed container

FAILED
Error restarting application: StagingError
```

It works great locally. I tried increasing memory to 1GB, didn't help either. Please help.

Comment: Do you see any more debug information if you run the `cf logs ...` command?  If not, can you try removing dependencies one-by-one to identify which dependency is causing the issue!

Comment: the log is identical to the above. Thanks for that suggestions - doing it now.

Comment: Did you find the issue? If so, can you share? It would be helpful for anyone else who might encounter a similar issue.